# how to save java swing ImageIcon image to file?

Tags: java, swing

I am using the following code for displaying the Image on the swing frame.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("image.jpeg");
icon.getImage().flush();
jLabel3.setIcon( icon );
```

I need a button which when clicked upon will save the image with a jpeg/png extension .

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Please consider looking at the question editor, learning what the different buttons in the toolbar can do for you - such as formatting your code to a more readable and understandable format. =) What are you specifically having issue with? What have you tried, and where's the problem?

Answer (score 10):

I usually do something like this

```
Image img = icon.getImage();

BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null),img.getHeight(null),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_ARGB);

Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
g2.dispose();
ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", new File("img.jpg"));
```

also try other image types like BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, checkout [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

you may also want to read this [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

hope it works for you

Answer (score 1):

consider useing [ImageIO.write(Image img, String type, File file)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) for writeing a Image to the filesystem.

You get an Image object from the ImageIcon with `getImage()`

You have to Implement a ActionListener for the Button, and then you are ready to go

Comment: The method write(RenderedImage, String, File) in the type ImageIO is not applicable for the arguments (Image, String, File)

Comment: try to cast the image to RenderedImage - should work - or repaint it to an new Buffered image as @Leon mentioned in his answer

Answer (score -1):

So the first part is implementing actionlistener so the button works when you click it. The JButton.

The second part is saving the image which i use ImageIo.write

See code below

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  private JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me!");


  public MyFrame() {
    button1.addActionListener(this);

    //... add buttons to frame ...
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Object src = evt.getSource();
    if (src == button1) {
      string imagename = icon.getDescription;


         try {
    // retrieve image
    BufferedImage bi = icon.getImage();
    File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
} catch (IOException e)


{
        //catch the exception here
    }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: BufferedImage bi = icon.getImage(); <- "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Image to BufferedImage"

Comment: BufferedImage bi = icon.getImage();

You will get "java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage"